# End Date and Start Date of Travel History for UK Visitor Visa Application

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas

I am currently in process of applying for visitor UK Visa. In the world travel history, they asked to list all countries that had been visited in the past 10 years. I visited Hong Kong from Jakarta for 5 days, but in between those days I went to Macau for a one-day trip. Do I list it as:

1. **Hong Kong**: Entry date from Jakarta -- Departure date for Macau
2. **Macau**: Entry date from Hong Kong -- Departure date for Hong Kong
3. **Hong Kong**: Entry date from Macau -- Departure Date for Jakarta

Or do I list it this way?

1. **Hong Kong**: Entry date from Jakarta -- Departure date for Jakarta
2. **Macau**: Entry date from Hong Kong -- Departure date for Hong Kong

Also, since the trip to Macau is a one day trip, the entry date and the departure date is he same. However, **I got an error message saying I should "enter an end date that is after the start date"**. Is anyone having the same issue as I do? Would be great to hear from other people and possibly get suggestions.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I would personally use the first option (list HK twice), as you did edit and re-enter Hong Kong twice (you probably have stamps for all those entries and exits in your passport, don’t you?).

As for the dates, this seems to be a bug or at least an oversight on their part, it does not even allow the use of the same date for transit.

You should probably contact them using the “Contact Us” link at the bottom of the page to point out the issue and ask for guidance.

Let us know what they tell you!

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your reply, it really helps! Seems like the issue that I'm facing in entering the date still exists and I can't contact their phone number as I'm from outside the UK..

Comment: The phone number should be reachable from anywhere in the world: +44 203 481 1736, Monday to Friday, 24 hours. There is however a £1.37 per minute cost, I don't know how they charge that. You can also [reach them via e-mail](https://contact-ukvi.homeoffice.gov.uk/app/international/payment/language/English), the cost is £5.48 including followups. Alternatively, you may try to contact your local consulate/embassy or VFS application centre, but chances are they will redirect you to those two channels.

Comment: My friend who lives in the UK tried to contact that number and asked about the same thing. In conclusion, the officer at the end of the line did not help and only repeatedly say something like they can not advise for anything and even asked for proofs if the issue actually exists :S